# Save selected items from UITableView on NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have an `UITableView` allows the user to select some rows. After selecting them, an accessory checkmarks appear.

I would like to know which is the best way to save the array of selected items to `NSUserDefaults`. I have attempted it in different ways without success.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // I also tried adding a NSMutableArray and assigning it to NSUserDefaults, without success. Logging, nil values.
    selectedProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [selectedProducts addObject:cell.textLabel.text];

    [userDefaults setObject:selectedProducts forKey:@"selectedProducts"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    /* The following code works, but it can only save the last object selected. 
    [userDefaults setObject:cell.textLabel.text forKey:@"selectedProducts"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Because alwayes you save a new instance of selectedProducts by alloc init.

so do this alloc init in your viewDidLoad:

```
selectedProducts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[[NSUserDefaults   standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedProducts"]];
if(selectedProducts == nil){
    selectedProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

and in tableview didselect do this

```
if ([selectedProducts containsObject: cell.textLabel.text] == NO) 
{
// Do something
   [selectedProducts addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much. How could I show a checkmark for the items that has been selected previously at previous times? I have tried ``if ([[userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedProducts"] isEqualTo:cell.textLabel.text]) { cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; }`` in ``viewDidLoad`` but I get an error of ``No known instance method for selector 'isEqualTo:'``. Thanks for your help Bhaskar.